# Gitlab CI $CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG is empty

Tags: scope, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I want to use the `$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG` to point our Selenium tests to the right dynamic environment, but the variable is empty.

During the *deployment* stage it has a proper value and I don't get why the variable is not available in every stage. The `echo` cmd prints an empty line.

```
Tests:
  image: maven:3.5.0-jdk-8
  stage: Tests and static code checks
  variables:
    QA_PUBLISH_URL: http://$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG-publish.test.com
  script:
      - echo $QA_PUBLISH_URL
      - echo $CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG    # empty
      - mvn clean -Dmaven.repo.local=../../.m2/repository -B -s ../../settings.xml -P testrunner install -DExecutionID="FF_LARGE_WINDOWS10" -DRunMode="desktopLocal" -DSeleniumServerURL="https://$QA_ZALENIUM_USER:$QA_ZALENIUM_PASS@zalenium.test.com/wd/hub" -Dcucumber.options="--tags @sanity" -DJenkinsEnv="test.com" -DSeleniumSauce="No" -DBaseUrl=$QA_PUBLISH_URL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG` is only available in the review JOB that has the environment set.

And currently (11.2) there is no way to move variables from one JOB to another, although you could:

```
echo -e -n "$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG" > ci_environment_slug.txt
```

in the review JOB and add the file to the artifacts:

```
artifacts:
  paths:
  - ci_environment_slug.txt
```

and in your `Tests` job, use

```
before_script:
- export CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG=$(cat ci_environment_slug.txt)
```

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I did.

Comment: Meanwhile there's a better way to do this: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job